# Regarding the automatic creation of a background when calling a Widget with showBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart

When calling a Widget with showBottomSheet in Flutter, a background is automatically created. I just want to display an amber-colored BottomSheetWidget, but a blue background is automatically created and displayed.
（For clarity, we are specifying `color: Colors.blue,`）

How can I remove the automatically created background widget when calling a Widget with showBottomSheet?

[image]

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ef06ab3ce0b822e6cc5db0575248e6e2)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  static final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) =>const BottomSheetWidget()),
              child: const Text('showBottomSheet'))),
    );
  }
}

class BottomSheetWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomSheetWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 300,
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is fine, just add constraints to the `ModalBottomSheet`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  context: context,
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth:100), //THIS
                  builder: (context) =>const BottomSheetWidget()),
              child: const Text('showBottomSheet'))),
    );
  }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thnks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!